# Rearrange divs through css

Tags: html, css

I have three 3 child div's with class span2, span7 and span3 respectively. When my browser width is below 763px I want it to be in this order span2, span3 and span7. How will I do that through css?

Here is my initial code:

```
<div class="row-fluid">    
    <div class="span2">           
    </div>      
    <div class="span7"> 
    </div>        
    <div class="span3">                                       
    </div>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this by using [flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) layout and flex [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) like this:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/44qxks3c/)**

```css
.row-fluid > div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
@media (max-width: 763px) {
    .row-fluid {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .span2 {
        order: 1;
    }
    .span7 {
        order: 3;
    }
    .span3 {
        order: 2;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">span2</div>
    <div class="span7">span7</div>
    <div class="span3">span3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that flex barely works, if at all, in IE10 and under.